# FF 51.0.1 (32-bit) - issue with Firebug - 'quick info/computed style'

Tags: firefox, firebug

I am using FF 51.0.1 (32-bit) and I have this issue with Firebug. When Firebug is not 'off', the window 'quick info/computed style' remains on the screen and is hidden. I barely can't click on the area where it is placed.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7joCxHiM5SWa1hkeFJwOFJ5dVU/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's obviously a bug in Firebug, though note that [Firebug's development is officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/). Reasons for this can be read at the related [Mozilla Hacks block post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).

It advises to switch to the Firefox DevTools, though the DevTools don't have that feature yet and I [couldn't find a request for it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/showdependencytree.cgi?id=991806&hide_resolved=1). So, you may [create one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Inspector&blocked=991806) and mark it as blocker of [bug 991806](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=991806).

Comment: Just saw your answer now. Thanks for taking the time to explain the context. After reading the articles, I think I will switch to DevTools. I am happy that FF is making this move and a bit sad that firebug team had to stay out of it. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Well, the head of the Firebug team is also part of the DevTools team. And I, as former volunteer Firebug contributor, while not (yet) coding for the DevTools, am at least trying to help Firebug users with the [migration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug) to them.